# Vertx SocketJS disconnects after few seconds of server being busy

Tags: websocket, sockjs, event-bus, vert.x

Need some help understanding on where disconnects occur (SocketJS, Vertx) and how timeouts can be configured.

I am creating *SockJSServer* along with creating eventBus bridge. Problem that I observer is frequent WebSocket connection disconnects. Looking at the websocket frames, I see pings every 5 seconds and heart-beats what I configured every 1/2 sec(what seem to take effect). However, once heart beats are being delayed for longer then 5 second disconnects comes with message  *c[3000,'Go away']*. As observed it happens when server is busy(doing something else on separate thread).

I have searched Vertx documentation and looked over vertx code and found few configuration parameter(which appear to be different across versions and documentation).

```
.putNumber("ping_interval", 120000)
                    .putNumber("session_timeout", 1200000)
                    .putNumber("heartbeat_period",500)
```

To be absolutely sure, I have tried different config that did not appear to have any impact. At this point, I think I have reached dead wall and need some help.

Vertx version 2.1P3

Server snipet

```
final SockJSServer server = vertx.createSockJSServer(httpServer);
server.bridge(new JsonObject().putString("prefix", "/eventbus")
                    .putNumber("ping_interval", 120000)
                    .putNumber("session_timeout", 1200000)
                    .putNumber("heartbeat_period",500),
new JsonArray().addObject(new JsonObject()),
new JsonArray().addObject(new JsonObject()));
```

Client code:

```
var eventBus = new EventBus('//hostX:12001/eventbus');
```

Comment: nobody had faced the same issue ?

Answer (score 2):

When you receive a SOCKET_IDLE event, you can't complete the event with a "true" parameter, as it indicates the socket must be closed:

`SockJSHandler.create(vertx,handlerOptions).bridge(options, event -> {
    boolean result = true;
    switch(event.type()) {
        case SOCKET_CREATED:
            LOGGER.info("Socket created");
            break;
        case SOCKET_IDLE:
            result = false;
            return;
        case SOCKET_CLOSED:
            LOGGER.info("Socket closed");
            break;
    }
    event.complete(result);
});`

Comment: Sure it is "return;" under "case SOCKET_IDLE"? not "break;"?

Comment: Yep, the idea is to not call event.complete for SOCKET_IDLE events, because this call will end up closing the socket. The switch statement is not really necessary, you can just use a single if statement to call event.complete only if the event is not SOCKET_IDLE.